# MYSQL: Show data based on result of other query. Want to merge the query

Tags: mysql

I have two queries, A and B. Query B can run only if i get the result from query A. But now i do both query separately. Below is my queries:

Query A

```
SELECT id, u_name, u_email, u_factory_id FROM wla_user WHERE email = 'john@gmail.com'
```

| id | u_name | u_email | u_factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Bird | john@gmail.com | 8 |

Query B

```
SELECT id, door_details, con_details, factory_id FROM wla_container WHERE factory_id = $u_factory_id
```

| id | door_details | con_details | factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 Tan | car spareparts | 8 |
| 1 | 3 Tan | motorcycle spareparts | 8 |
| 1 | 3 Tan | kitchen | 8 |

Now, i just want to make it with single query only. Can anyone know how to merge hat queries?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a union query:

```sql
SELECT id, u_name, u_email, u_factory_id
FROM wla_user
WHERE email = 'john@gmail.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, door_details, con_details, factory_id
FROM wla_container
WHERE factory_id = $u_factory_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html), when you need the result from a query A for running the query B, you can use nested queries like so:

**Query**

```
SELECT id, door_details, con_details, factory_id 
FROM wla_container 
WHERE factory_id IN (
  SELECT u_factory_id 
  FROM wla_user 
  WHERE u_email = 'john@gmail.com'
);
```

| id | door_details | con_details | factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 Tan | car spareparts | 8 |
| 2 | 3 Tan | motorcycle spareparts | 8 |
| 3 | 3 Tan | kitchen | 8 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)